# SSRS - How can I conditionally send a report to a mail address

Tags: reporting-services

Let me specify the environment. The client has UI for entering orders in SQL Server database. A Windows Service one another machine is processing these orders from database at particular intervals. Sometimes the Windows service is stopped then orders piles up. To avoid that I have created a SQL Server Report which is run at an interval of 5mins. It checks how many orders are processed and creates a status report. What I want, if count of processed order is zero then the report be mailed to system administrator. Then he will  check the machine where the service is hosted and restart the service, so that all rework is avoided. So the question is how to implement this conditional delivery of report. In short, if count is zero no report be mailed otherwise it must.

Answer (score 2):

This is 4 years late, but for anyone who stumbles onto this, a [Data Driven Subscription](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159150.aspx) will do the trick.

In short, you can create a query that returns the recipients if there is data, or NULL if there isn't any data.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem with SSRS 2005 (not sure about 2008) - there's no easy way to stop an empty report from being sent.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160216062252/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/bimusings/archive/2005/07/29/445080.aspx)

The solution I had to use (and yes, I know it's ugly, inefficient, and somewhat embarrassing...), is to run your search query in a stored procedure. If rows are not found, cause an error. If rows are found, re-run your query.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE

IF @@RowCount = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT 1/0
ELSE
SELECT * FROM TABLE
END
```

Returning an error will prevent the subscription from emailing the report.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using Data Driven Subscription, where we have to put some SQL condition query in which it return ToEmail Address if data is present then ToEmail Address will not be blank or NULL
Below are some code that will help

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 from Table where datefield = CONVERT(varchar(13),GETDATE() -1 ,23)+' 00:00:00.000' )
           Select   ToEmailAddress ='abc.pqr@xyz.com'
ELSE
           Select ToEmailAddress =''
```